# What should I do about this vanity that won't sit tight to the wall due to trim molding?

Tags: bathroom, trim, remodeling

Slight goof during a bathroom remodel - the vanity we got won't sit tight to the wall due to the trim molding.

Obviously one option is to return the vanity and get a new one (ugh!)

Or I could let it be as-is, and live with the small gap between counter and wall.

Or I could cut into the trim to seat the legs further back, and hope that the eye isn't drawn down there much (it's not in a major sightline for the bathroom).

I am favoring the latter, I think.  What do you think?

[image: Wall Gap][image: Floor trim]

Comment: I think my fix would be a backsplash. A single row of tile might look nice, or just a faux marble strip. It's not important that the cabinet be tight to the wall--just the counter.

Comment: That said, this is a design/decorating question and therefore off-topic.

Comment: Id just some type of backsplash is necessary regardless of gap or water will sit against the drywall as caulk/silicone tends to be neglected until its too late

Comment: The vanity comes with a 3" marble backsplash that attaches to the bach.  However that'll also have the same gap.  Note that the gap is visible from the side too.

Comment: How about filling the gap?

Comment: If the backsplash is wide enough, attach it to the wall, not the cabinet.

Comment: If you leave a gap, things will fall down there.  If any gap is not sealed against water, you'll get water dribbling down the back at some point.

Answer (score 10):

If that leg can be unscrewed and moved over 1/2 inch, that would be my first choice. If not, then I'd get a coping saw and cut the leg to fit the trim.

Comment: Great ideas, did not even think of either of those.  I will check if it can be moved.

Answer (score -1):

I would cut the trim back a little so it ends just before the leg.  It shouldn't look too bad, especially if it isn't in an obvious place for the eye to notice.

Comment: I absolutely would not do that. It'll look atrocious.

Comment: The room is much more permanent than the furniture in it.  And you'd still have to finish the bottom of the wall with something to cover the ends of the wall cladding, and the edge of the flooring.  Removing all the skirting board/trim and replacing it with something thinner might look OK, but thats a lot of work for one cabinet.